# How do I insert DataGridView values from selected columns and rows into ListView?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I've just started learning VB.Net and im trying to move values from my DataGridView to ViewList. I followed some other tutorial online but I still couldn't solve it.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As System.Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvGPU.CellContentClick
    Dim senderGrid = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    If TypeOf senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex) Is DataGridViewButtonColumn AndAlso
       e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

        Dim x As String = dgvGPU.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString()

        Form4.ListView1.Items.Add(x)
        Form4.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're having trouble with the ListView item addition.  It should look something like this:

```
ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {x}))
```